# DIV on top of html5 Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am having trouble with this and need help! I am trying to use a video as a background and then put text and images on top of it in a div.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<section id="VideoSection>  
    <div id="VideoText">Testing 123</div>
    <video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</section>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
video#bgvid {
    z-index: -2;
}

#VideoText{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: video#bgvid {
  z-index: -2; position:absolute; /*add this also*/ and give `position:relative` to parent .

}

Comment: As a first, i would advise you to stay out of negative numbers in CSS, they make things confusing. Try reading this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp And put position:absolute/relative to video#bgvid too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ***[-DEMO-](http://jsfiddle.net/z9K3T/1/)***

```
<section id="VideoSection">

    <div id="VideoText">Testing 123</div>
    <video id=bgvid autoplay muted poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/poster.png">
        <source id="mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source id="ogv" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
    </video>
 </section>
```

Css:

```
video#bgvid {
    z-index: -2;
}

#VideoText{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

then add `position:relative;` to `#VideoSection` so that you will be able to use position absolute on the text

```
#VideoSection{
    position:relative;
}
```

## [***-Demo-***](http://jsfiddle.net/z9K3T/3/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `position:relative` to parent element and give `position:absolute` to child and then give `top` or `left` value. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/govuzofe/1/edit)**.

```
section#VideoSection{position:relative;}

video#bgvid 
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#VideoText{
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top:12px;
}
```